# Compare two string values after trimming

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dates.

```
ReleaseDates = "11/2/2016";
LiveDate =  "11/02/2016";
```

In the above two dates are same. But in my below coding it returns FALSE.

```
if (ReleaseDates.Contains(LiveDate.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' })))
 {

 }
```

Comment: can you use `DateTime` instead of strings?.. If you parse to `DateTime` then it is trivial

Comment: Perhaps you want to parse them as dates and compare that?

Comment: Well one of the values is `11/2/2016` and another is `11/02/2016` so of course they're not the same - `LiveDate.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' })` might not work how you think, it'll remove a `0` from the beginning of the string for example if it was instead `011/2/2016` it would become `11/2/2016`

Comment: I would never understand why using strings for dates. Never.

Comment: `TrimStart` removes only **leading** occurrences of a set of characters

Comment: _I have two dates_ - No you don't, you have two _strings_.  You would be better off using `DateTime.TryParseExact` to convert them both to dates and then compare them.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because `TrimStart` removes characters at the *start* of the string. It looks like `LiveDate` has no zeros at the beginning; the character `'0'` that you want to trim is at index 3, preceded by other characters. That is why it is not getting trimmed.

Comparing strings representing dates is an error-prone strategy. You would be better off parsing both strings, and comparing the results as `DateTime` objects.

In general, you should keep dates as objects designed for date representation - for example, `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`. This would let you customize date representation for display purposes, and avoid errors when date format changes from mm/dd to dd/mm.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not comparing dates, you are comparing two strings that are not the same. Your best shot here is parsing first and then comparing.

```
DateTime releaseDate = DateTime.Parse(ReleaseDates);
DateTime liveDate = DateTime.Parse(LiveDate);
if (releaseDate == liveDate) // This should be true.
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Anyway, why using strings for dates?